# How to make Calendar icon show in React Date Picker?

Tags: react-datepicker

I'm using React Date Picker, which I installed via `npm i react-datepicker`. Everything works except the calendar icon which doesn't display. The docs says to add `showIcon` to the JSX element to display the calendar icon, this does not show the icon, it only makes the JSX element bigger.

This is my code

```js
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";


export default function Form() {
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState<[Date | null, Date | null]>([
    null,
    null,
  ]);
  const [startDate, endDate] = dateRange;

  return (
    <form>
      <DatePicker
        showIcon
        selectsRange={true}
        startDate={startDate}
        endDate={endDate}
        onChange={(update) => {
          console.log("Selected Date Range:", update);
          setDateRange(update);
        }}
        minDate={new Date()}
        withPortal
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```